# Insert using different conditions with same date - Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

```
--Table Creation
CREATE TABLE BOOK_TEST (BOOK_ID VARCHAR2(20), DEP_IND VARCHAR2(1), INSERT_DATE DATE);
--Insert data
INSERT INTO BOOK_TEST VALUES ('B100','Y','20122016');
INSERT INTO BOOK_TEST VALUES ('B101','Y','20122016');
INSERT INTO BOOK_TEST VALUES ('B101','N','20122016');
INSERT INTO BOOK_TEST VALUES ('B102','Y','20122016');
INSERT INTO BOOK_TEST VALUES ('B103','Y','20122016');
INSERT INTO BOOK_TEST VALUES ('B104','N','20122016');
INSERT INTO BOOK_TEST VALUES ('B105','N','20122016');
INSERT INTO BOOK_TEST VALUES ('B105','Y','20122016');
INSERT INTO BOOK_TEST VALUES ('B106','N','30092016');
INSERT INTO BOOK_TEST VALUES ('B107','Y','03032016');
COMMIT;
```

Question:
I want to insert above all records into target table(target_book) as one booking id has one indicator (B101-'Y') then it's populate into target table and same time suppose (B101-'N') booking id has an different indicator is 'N' then this records should not comes to target table (target_book).All the above two conditions should comes under the same date and this is the very big challenging I'm facing.

SAMPLE QUERY:-

```
CREATE TABLE TARGET_BOOK AS SELECT * FROM BOOK_TEST WHERE (--conditions?)
```

Finally my target_book table should be populated with below result.

```
B_ID DEP_IND DATE
B100 Y 20122016
B101 Y 20122016
B102 N 20122016
B103 Y 20122016
B104 Y 20122016
B105 Y 20122016
B106 N 30092016
B107 Y 03032016
```

Comment: "B104 Y 20122016" is a typo and shall be "B104 N 20122016" I guess?

Comment: No Thorsten, It should "B104 Y 20122016" only. It has combination of "Y" and "N".

Comment: Well, I only see an insert for 'N', no insert for 'Y'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE TARGET_BOOK AS 
SELECT BOOK_ID, DEP_IND, INSERT_DATE
FROM (
   SELECT BOOK_ID, DEP_IND, INSERT_DATE,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BOOK_ID 
                             ORDER BY CASE 
                                         WHEN DEP_IND = 'Y' THEN 0 
                                         ELSE 1
                                      END)  rn
   FROM BOOK_TEST)  t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Using `ROW_NUMBER` you can enumerate records within each `BOOK_ID` partition and give precedence to records having `DEP_IND = 'Y'`.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos. While executing your code am getting "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error. I can't find where i have to change. One more request, Without using partition can we able form a query?.

Comment: Thank u. It's working fine. Without partition  is possible?